# Django Form Wizard, SessionWizardView Import Error

Tags: django, importerror, formwizard, django-formwizard

I want to implement a django form wizard. I read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) about it but when I add the 
'from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views' import SessionWizardView' to my view, i get 
"No module named views" .

I searched the "views" from shell, but nope there is no view module under the formtools.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the wrong documentation page - the page you link is the documentation of the current development trunk, probably you're using Django 1.3:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/

Comment: I have added the new answer, as I stumbled-upon this one, while looking for the formtools import Error exception - the selected answer is only valid for prev django version, and the shared resource link is no more.

Answer (score 2):

I am answering, as the link in the selected answer is no more available - reason being, the support for `django` version `1.3` (also `1.4`) has been discontinued.

As per latest `django 1.8` (`1.9` is in dev/alpha mode) the `django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views` has been deprecated.

Porting your django project gives you **No module named formtools.wizard.views - from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView** exception.

> This code is now distributed separately from Django, for easier
>   maintenance and to trim the size of Django’s codebase. In Django 1.8,
>   importing from django.contrib.formtools will no longer work. The new
>   formtools package is named django-formtools, with a main module called
>   formtools. Version 1.0 includes the same two primary features that the
>   code included when it shipped with Django: a helper for form previews
>   and a form wizard view.

**Solution**: For `Linux` users - use `sudo` in case you're not `root` user

```
 pip install django-formtools==1.0
```

Change your app’s import statements to reference the new packages:

`from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView` to

`from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView`